# Firebase - custom network provider

Tags: android, firebase, admob, okhttp

I need to add custom network provider such as Okhttp in Admob/Firebase (android).
How to do that?

I need something like

```
Firebase.useProvider(okHttp);
// any other code here...
```

Comment: If you'd like a feature to be added to Firebase, you can request it here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/. I recommend that you tell a bit more about your use-case when you enter the feature

Comment: i just need to add custom header in every admob http request